# Visual Studio freezes often when solution is opened from network

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having an issue where Visual Studio performance is horrendous when the solution is loaded from a networked drive.  This does not seem to happen to other developers, just me.

After running procmon and monitoring the devenv process, i notice that one key difference between a project opened from a local path vs a networked path is that the project opened from the networked path is trying to execute Operation 'CreateFile' on path 'C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace\kpg.apps' 1000s of time.  the Result is 'NAME NOT FOUND'.

Does anyone know why visual studio is trying to do this for the project opened from the network and how i can resolve or at the very least stop it from attempting this operation?

thanks

Comment: Hi, I don't believe this question is for SO, I'd advise you to contact VS if you do not find anything else.

Comment: Do you have some suspicious extensions or add-ons installed?

Comment: Check task manager. Memory/processor usage maxed out?

Comment: I have run VS in /SafeMode to disable all add-ins, but still the problem persists.

Comment: @philip, Visual Studio is not a company, it's a development IDE from MS.  i do feel it is an appropriate topic for SO since it is development related (no different than asking about Eclipse or other ides).  but i could be wrong.

Comment: @mike I know that, but VS has its own support within Microsoft. Okay I see, just thought he might get better answers elsewhere :). p.s. I never stated it was a company.

Comment: Is "kpg.apps" the name of the server or share?

Comment: So this is related to offline files as written in my answer.

Comment: I've had this problem before too.  I fixed it by switching to FTP instead of the network share

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help to disable offline files (which are stored by default at the location you mentioned): Go to control panel, Sync Center to manage that.

Also, some servers may be configured to force offline files on the share - but this may not be the case when it works for other users.

Comment: this does resolve the issue with VS trying to create the file in /CSC, however it is still very slow since it's now trying to create/query the file from the networked path.  While it is successful in dowing so, i'ts slow.  So i'm guessing what VS was trying to do is cache the file locally, but since it is unable to do so either because of write permission to the cache location or perhaps the size limit for that cache has been exceeded, it was failing and once it fails just keeps retrying.

Comment: Maybe you could check times in ProcMon? Do you find anything that takes unusual long?

Comment: hmm...i set up a partnership to cache the networked files.  now i see in procmon its constantly trying to access these files from the cache (/CSC...) several times a second (operations are CreateFile, SetBasicInfo, QUeryFileInfo, CloseFile).  that is resulting in continued slowness.  don't get this...

Comment: anyway, i mark yours as answer since it was most helpful i think...(still working to figure this out)

Comment: What about synchronization conflicts? Maybe you could compare these new ideas with the "other developers"?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have either:

1. An overactive virus scanner or external application interfering with Visual Studio
2. or, a heinous add-on/extension for Visual Studio

The easiest way to determine which of these two is to open the solution in Safe Mode, which you can do from a Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
X:\>devenv /safemode \\unc\path\to\your\solution.sln
```

This will turn off all the bells and whistles while loading your solution.

If it is still slow, this is most likely not a Visual Studio problem. Keep in mind though that network resources and Windows rarely play well together. Numerous "trust" settings affect the behavior of files loaded from UNC paths.

That folder is [Windows Client Side Caching](https://code.google.com/p/dngrep/issues/detail?id=69), so this is not a VS problem.

Comment: If it was a virus scanner, ProcMon would've revealed that.

Comment: @JeffRSon: unless they had a lower level hook.